# testing websockets with postman new api

Tags: javascript, testing, websocket, postman

I am trying to get the postman api for websockets working, however I can't even make a connection:

When I try to make a connection

```
ws://localhost:5001/socket.io/
```

results in:

```
Error: Unexpected server response: 400 //for ws
```

```js
//index.js
const port=5001
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //handshake and hydrate and test
  console.log("Client connected",socket.id);
  socket.on("test", (data)=>{
    console.log("test data is:",data)
    socket.emit("test", "server heard you!")
  });
```

what is the proper url string to connect to a socket.io/express/nodejs server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket.io supports `polling` and `websocket` [transports](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#transports).

To connect with Postman's WebSocket client, we have to explicitly set the WebSocket transport while connecting to a Socket.io server.
This can be done by setting the `transport=websocket` parameter in the connection URL.

In your case, it will be: `ws://localhost:5001/socket.io/?transport=websocket`.

Comment: this is fantastic. and yet: while this connects me, every request I send ends with a disconnect... is that normal? inspecting the message section I see this error:
1005 No Status Received:
 
Missing status code even though one was expected.

is this status code something I also have to explicitly set: if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @altruios That might be happening because socket.io expects messages to be serialized in its special format, an invalid message results in disconnection.

For example, if you send `2` (ping) the server will respond with `3` (pong). Similarly, an outgoing message is prefixed with `42`.

Now suppose you have to post a message to room `new_user`, it will be serialized as: `42["new_user", "<Your Message>"]`.

Comment: I know it's a bit confusing, I will share a detailed gist/doc explaining this in detail soon.

Comment: that seems to be the root of it. the proper message format is what exactly? <int>{message#} [ <str>{event} ,<obj>{data} ] ..?

Comment: gah, I can't seem to get anything sending back and forth... I have a nodemon on the server - with a console logging when a new client connects... and... nothing... postman says it's connected, but nothing on the server side... :/

Comment: It's `<int>[<str>{event} ,<str>{data}]`. Example message: `42["<event-name>", "<str-data>"]`.

Comment: okay, with that... looking at the above code. postman 'connects' and I send either of these. 1['connection','test'] or 1['test','testing123'] I would expect the server to respond - but nothing... also, is messages sent only ever 1 at a time in postman, or batch them in a single message? - in addition: the server responds with a 2[] which a null character inside

Comment: You have to always prefix the message with `42` (instead of `1`) like this: `42["connection", "test"]`. Also note, I replaced single quotes with double quotes to make the payload a valid JSON string.

Comment: 42... the answer was literally 42... (thanks - I thought you meant sequential ordering, like the first message is 1, the server responds with a 2, then you send a 3...)

Comment: That's what I would say if 42 worked... still getting an empty 2 from the server (and disconnecting shortly after)

Comment: On ping (`2`), if the client does not answer with a pong (`3`) within `pingTimeout`, the server considers that the connection is closed.

To avoid this, you can just set the "Reconnection attempts" as `1` (or more) in the WebSocket "Settings" tab (under the connection URL).

Comment: note... it seems to send a 2 regardless of what I do after a set period of time... while it 'sees' the websocket: I'm not convinced it's actually connected, as no confirmation from the server is sent, or logged - and nothing I send seems to get through...

Comment: understood: I'll try all this on another machine just in case it's something weird with mine... but yeah: reconnecting every 30 seconds or so... and no acknowledgement from the server that anything is connected :/